# How to edit a property file using Jenkins once code is cloned to Jenkins work space

Tags: git, maven, jenkins

I want to edit a property file before executing my pom.xml using Jenkins job.

Is this somehow possible?

I created a Jenkins job with git repository. The Jenkins job is successfully able to clone the git code to the work space. Now since I cloned the code to the Jenkins work space, I want to change some value of the property file download.

Please, suggest.

Comment: Maybe by `sed` or `awk`?

Comment: @ElpieKay .. could you plesae explain with and example

Comment: In the `Build` section add `Execute Shell`, where you can write a shell script. For example a one-line command `sed -i -e "s/foo=abc/foo=xyz/" pom.xml` changes "foo=abc" to "foo=xyz" in the file "pom.xml". It could be any other script, like Python or Ruby.

Comment: ok .. will try this today and will update you